# NoClassDefFoundError on Android Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android

I write a little app and I use external library (`.jar` file imported to my project in Android Studio). Everything works great on android device emulator (API 23) and my LG G3 (Android 5.0) but I want to use that app on my old Xperia S with Android 4.1 too. When I tried to debug it on my Xperia S I get `NoClassDefFoundError`. Is there any solution for my problem? I read about multidex but I don't know how to do that and I'm not sure that is what I'm looking for.

logcat:

> 03-31 16:46:44.643 9719-9719/com.example.dell.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.PMMLManager.(PMMLManager.java:47)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelManager.(ModelManager.java:56)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.(ModelEvaluator.java:109)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.RegressionModelEvaluator.(RegressionModelEvaluator.java:46)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory.newModelManager(ModelEvaluatorFactory.java:85)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory.newModelManager(ModelEvaluatorFactory.java:45)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelManagerFactory.newModelManager(ModelManagerFactory.java:66)
>                                                                                     at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelManagerFactory.newModelManager(ModelManagerFactory.java:46)
>                                                                                     at com.example.dell.myapplication.EvaluatorListUtil.createEvaluatorList(EvaluatorListUtil.java:27)
>                                                                                     at com.example.dell.myapplication.PRActivity.createForm(PRActivity.java:137)
>                                                                                     at com.example.dell.myapplication.PRActivity$1.onItemSelected(PRActivity.java:220)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
android {  
    compileSdkVersion 23  
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"    

defaultConfig {  
        applicationId "com.example.dell.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':pmml-android-1.0')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: What is your miminSdkVersion in gradle? Tried changing it?

Comment: put your logcat here

Comment: show `build.gradle` and `logcat`

Comment: post your logcat..........

Comment: Anybody can help me?